# I have following build failed error in xcode

Tags: xcode, file, build, node-modules, declare

Showing Recent Issues
Build input file cannot be found: '/Users/jan/GodojoClientRn/node_modules/react-native-screens/ios/RNSScreenStackHeaderConfig.m'. Did you forget to declare this file as an output of a script phase or custom build rule which produces it?